# C++ Arithmetic With Mixed Integral Types That Causes Overflow

Tags: c++, integer-overflow, type-promotion

I have done some tests in VC++2010 mixing operands of different sizes that cause overflow in add operation:

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    __int8 a=127;
    __int8 b=1;
    __int16 c=b+a;
    __int8  d=b+a;
    printf("c=%d,d=%d\n",c,d);

    return 0;
}

//result is: c=128, d=-128
```

I don't understand why c==128!  My understanding is that in both additions, b+a are still considered addition of 2 signed **8 bit** variables. So the result is an overflow i.e. -128.  **After that**, the result is then promoted to 16 bit signed int for the first assignment operation and c should still get a 16 bit -128 value.  Is my understanding correct?  The c++ standard is a bit difficult to read. Chapter 4 seems talking about integeral promotion but I can't find anything related to this specific example.

Comment: Integral promotion is exactly what happens, via the usual arithmetic conversions; see [expr]/10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My understanding is that in both additions, b+a are still considered addition of 2 signed 8 bit variables. So the result is an overflow i.e. -128.

No, the promotion happens before the `+` is evaluated, not after it. The addition happens when both `a` and `b` are positive. Both numbers are promoted to `int`s for an addition, added as two positive numbers, and then converted to a 16-bit short. At no point in the process does the result become negative due to an overflow, hence the end result of 128.

Arguably, this makes sense: the behavior of `a` and `b` matches that of two numbers in mathematics, making it more intuitive to language practitioners.

Answer (score 1):

### It's integral promotion.

> <sup>1</sup> A prvalue of an integer type other than bool, char16_t, char32_t, or wchar_t whose integer conversion rank (4.13) is less than the rank of int can be converted to a prvalue of type int if int can represent all the values of the source type; otherwise, the source prvalue can be converted to a prvalue of type unsigned int. [§ 4.5]

In this statement

```
 __int16 c=b+a;
```

> First, all `char` and `short int` values are automatically elevated to `int`. This process is called **integral promotion**. Next, all operands are converted up to the type of the largest operand, which is called **type promotion**. [Herbert Schildt]

The *values* of variables `b` and `a` will be promoted to `int` and then the operation applies on them.

Answer (score 0):

In twos-complement integer representation, a signed value is represented by setting the highest bit.  This allows the machine to add and subtract binary integers with the same instructions, regardless of whether the integer is signed.

```
  a = 127 == 0x7F == 0b01111111
+ b =   1 == 0x01 == 0b00000001
-------------------------------
  c = 128 == 0x80 == 0b10000000
  d =-128 == 0x80 == 0b10000000
```

The variables `c` and `d` may have different types, but different types of integers are merely different interpretations of a single binary value.  As you can see above, the binary value fits in 8 bits just fine.  Since the standard requires terms of a mathematical expression to be zero- or sign-extended (promoted) to the size of a machine word *before* any math is done and neither operand will be sign-extended, the result is always `0b10000000` no matter what type the operands are.

In summary, the difference between the results is that, to a 16 bit integer the sign bit is `0b1000000000000000` (which `a+b` doesn't have), and to an 8 bit integer the sign bit is `0b10000000` (which `a+b` does have).